# Is there a function that is the quotient of all positive integers less than or equal to $n$

Tags: notation

We all know factorials ($n! = 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot \ldots \cdot n$). Is there such function (or operator, or etc...) were $n$ will be divided by all the numbers before $n$. Somthing like this:

$$n \div \cdots \div 1$$

If it exists, what is it called and how do you notate it?

Comment: How about $f(n)=\frac1{n!}$?

Comment: How do you define the quotient of $1$ and $2$ for example, if you were to define such a function? This definition seems somewhat unclear.

Comment: Question is quite unclear. Can you elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Division is not a commutative operation, meaning a/b does not equal b/a ( unless b=+-a, both not equal to zero). Thus, the expression  n ÷ (n-1) ÷ (n-2) ÷ ...÷ 2 ÷ 1 does not make any sense unless we: 1. Take use of Pemdas (order of operations), or 2. Insert parantheses in desired location.   If we use pemdas, the expression n ÷ (n-1) ÷ (n-2) ÷ ...÷ 2 ÷ 1 is equal to n/(n-1)!    Here, n is assumed to be a natural number.